# How to use Node.js in Postgraphile mutations?

Tags: node.js, graphql, postgraphile

I am making an application that shows information about different users, which is taken from third party API. **I save this information in my own format with multiple tables in PostgreSQL to keep track of any changes to the data and provide history of changes** (*third party API only provides current data*).

I want to use GraphQL, specifically [Postgraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/) to simplify backend development. But there is one use case which I can't find a way to implement with Postgraphile. Here is what I want to implement:

1. User wants to see an updated information
2. GraphQL mutation query is sent to the server, something like this:

```
mutation UpdateUserData($userid: Int) {
    updateUser(id: $userid) {
        field1,
        field2,
        relatedObjects {
            field3,
            filed3
        }
    }
}
```

3. Server makes an API request to third party server, processes data, makes some calculations and updates the database
4. Requested fields are returned to client

I know that this type of [custom mutations can be implemented with database functions](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/custom-mutations/) like [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql.html) or [PLV8](https://plv8.github.io/), but they can't make http requests and **I already have most of the logic  for data processing in Typescript**, so would like to use it.

**Is there a way to create a custom mutation that will call JavaScript function** which has access to Node.js modules, interfaces and classes that I already created?

One solution that I think will work:

1. Call REST endpoint on my server, like `/update_user?id=$userid`
2. User data is loaded from third party API and database is updated
3. Client receives response, like `Update successful`
4. Normal GraphQL query is called to get the data

Is there a better way of satisfying this use case?

Answer (score 1):

This part is a bit hidden in the documentation, but the easiest way to add mutations written in JavaScript is the [`makeExtendSchemaPlugin`](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-extend-schema-plugin/).

Here you can define type definitions in SDL and implement resolvers in JS.

Answer (score 1):

What I want is to utilize extremely convenient Postgraphile queries for front-end, and to write my back-end logic in my framework of choice with my ORM of choice with their own workflows (so [makeExtendSchemaPlugin](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-extend-schema-plugin/) is not and option), **but** reuse Postgraphile for return types of mutations.

In general, I rely on Postgraphile as the graphql server for my app, and put mutations under it's schema by [stitching](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/stitching) Postgraphile schema and my mutations schemas, with mutations resolvers [delegating](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/stitching/docs/approaches/schema-extensions#schema-delegation) to Postgraphile schema. `additionalGraphQLContextFromRequest` provides DI container to my resolvers, so they have a way to call buisiness services. `makeProcessSchemaPlugin` is the place where stiching happens. [codegen](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen) generates types so typescript complains when schema+resolvers+services doesn't add up.

Here is my setup:

```
- postgraphile.ts
- postgraphile.graphql
- types.ts
- services
  - base.graphql
  - document
    - service.ts
    - schema.graphql
    - resolver.ts
  - user
    - service.ts
    - schema.graphql
    - resolver.ts
  - ... other domains
```

`postgraphile.ts` [set up as library](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-library/):

```js
export const setupPostgraphile = () => postgraphile(connString, schema, {
    additionalGraphQLContextFromRequest: async (req) => {
        // get DI cradle I previously set up in Fastify and put to resolvers context
        return {
            cradle: (req._fastifyRequest as FastifyRequest).server.cradle
        } as AppResolverContext;
    },
    appendPlugins: [
      MutationResolversSchemaPlugin
    ]
});

const MutationResolversSchemaPlugin = makeProcessSchemaPlugin((schema) => {
    // save schema file ourselves instead of using postgraphile plugin because
    // after stiching it will have duplicates of our types giving
    // '...type tried to redefine...' errors
    if (!isProd) {
        writeFileSync('./postgraphile.graphql', printSchema(schema));
    }

    const mutationResolvers: MutationResolvers<AppResolverContext> = {
        ...documentResolvers(schema),
        ...userResolvers(schema),
        // all other resolvers
    };

    return stitchSchemas({
        subschemas: [schema],
        // do NOT include postgraphile.schema, it will nullify Postgraphile resolvers
        typeDefs: loadFilesSync<GraphQLSchema>('./services/**/*.graphql'),
        resolvers: {
            Mutation: mutationResolvers
        }
    });
});
```

`document/schema.graphql`, note that **Document is a Postgraphile type from `postgraphile.graphql`**:

```
input DocumentInput {
    title: String
}

extend type Mutation {
    createDocument(doc: DocumentInput!): Document!
}
```

`document/resolver.ts`, types Query and QueryDocumentArgs are from codegen:

```js
export const documentResolvers: AppMutationsSubresolver<
    'createDocument'
> = (postgraphileSchema) => ({
    createDocument: {
        selectionSet: '{ id }',
        resolve: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
            const result = await context.cradle.documentService.createDocument(args.doc);

            return delegateToSchema({
                schema: postgraphileSchema,
                operation: 'query',
                fieldName: 'document' as keyof Query['document'],
                args: {id: result.id} as QueryDocumentArgs,
                context,
                info
            });
        }
    }
});
```

`document/service.ts`:

```js
export class DocumentService {
    // DI setting up bla bla bla
    
    async createDocument(dto: DocumentUpdateDTO) {
        // my perfectly normal service code
        ...

        await this.em.flush();

        // return something which holds 'id' of created object, it will be used
        // to query from Postgraphile
        return serialize(doc); 
    }
}
```

`postgraphile.graphql` is just a dump of Postgraphile schema (original, without my mutations) for IDE completions.

`types.ts` to have IDe blame e.g. when I forgot some mutation or misspel some type, types are from codegen:

```js
export type AppResolverContext = {
    cradle: AppCradle; // my DI container type, I use awilix
}

// shorthand type for resolvers
export type AppMutationsSubresolver<
    MutationsSubset extends keyof MutationResolvers<AppResolverContext>
> = (postgraphileSchema: GraphQLSchema) => Pick<MutationResolvers<AppResolverContext>, MutationsSubset>
```

`base.graphql`:

```
type Mutation
```

Finally, doing mutation like this from front-end *actually works*, redirecting result to full-featured Postgraphile type:

```
mutation {
  createDocument(doc: {name: "ololo"}) {
    id, name
  }
}
```

*Graphql infra got really awesome recently.*

There seems to be good alternative way: instead of stiching, make a [type merging gateway](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/stitching/docs/approaches/type-merging#unidirectional-merges), making your mutations schemas returning stub types names after Postgraphile types, and instructing schema stiching how to merge Postgraphile types by IDs. I wanted to keep things explicit and non-gateway, and didn't try it.